# What does the ei= code in a Google link signify?

Tags: macos, firefox, google-search

Whenever I hit <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> in Firefox I get redirected to a Google search page.
I would expect it to just go to `www.google.com` but instead it sends me to a link that looks like this:

```
https://www.google.nl/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=VARIABLE_PART
```

The part after `ei=` changes everytime I hit the keyboard shortcut.

What does this part mean? Why does it change?

I'm on Mountain Lion 10.8.5 and Firefox v28.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ei value appears to be some sort of timestamp generated for the search. Check out the following link for more information: http://blog.deedpolloffice.com/articles/decoding-ei-parameter